# JavaScript error when an empty object is alone on left-hand side

Tags: javascript, node.js

*Note: It's hard to search for `{} == 0` in google*

I'm experiencing very exotic behaviour while using node.js:

```
obj == {}
```

works, and obviously dumps out `false`, but

```
{} == obj
```

and

```
{} === obj
```

Fails with an error: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '=='`

Why aren't we allowed to switch rhs and lhs in this case? Why can't we place {} alone on lhs?

---

---

```js
const obj = {};

console.log(obj == {});

console.log({} == obj);

console.log({} === obj);
```

Comment: `{}` is interpreted as a code block and not as an empty object literal. Try with `({} == obj)`

Comment: block vs obj - There are dupes on it